# Seaborn barplot with estimator set to median does not plot the error bars correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am using seaborn to make some barplots with error bars. I need to change the estimator to `np.median`, and I also want error bars with a confidence interval of 80%. When I change the estimator, the error bars are plotted uncentered on the median. Is there a way to get the error to estimate correctly using the median estimator?

With `estimator=np.average`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
            sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
            sns.barplot(x='SurveyMetrics',
                              y='value',
                              hue='Stimulus',
                              data=df_melt,
                              palette=colors,
                              estimator=np.average,
                              ci=0.80)
```

[image: estimator set to np.average]

With `estimator=np.median`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
            sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
            sns.barplot(x='SurveyMetrics',
                              y='value',
                              hue='Stimulus',
                              data=df_melt,
                              palette=colors,
                              estimator=np.median,
                              ci=0.80)
```

[image: estimator set to np.median]

Comment: Why do you think this is incorrect?

Comment: @SayeedDK The errorbars are calculated via [bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics))